# Why does overriding __iter__ throws RecursionError?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, iterable

I want to override the `__iter__` method of the `ExternalIter` which is defined in an external library so I cannot change the source code of `ExternalIter` class. I implemented two different ways of overriding in the `MyIter2` and `MyIter3`.

```
class ExternalIter:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = iter([
            (1, 2),
            (3, 4),
            (5, 6),
            (7, 8),
            (9, 10)
        ])
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.x)
    
class MyIter2(ExternalIter):
    
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                i, j = super().__next__()
                yield i
                yield j
            except StopIteration:
                break
    
class MyIter3(ExternalIter):
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for i, j in super().__iter__():
            yield i
            yield j
```

Original behavior of the `ExternalIter` is the following:

```
for i in ExternalIter():
    print(i)
# (1, 2)
# (3, 4)
# (5, 6)
# (7, 8)
# (9, 10)
```

I want to override the behavior of the `__iter__` as in the following example:

```
for i in MyIter2():
    print(i)
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8
# 9
# 10
```

`MyIter2` works as excepted. However, an alternative way of overriding as I did in `MyIter3` throws `RecursionError`.

```
for i in MyIter3():
    print(i)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4e1114201cac> in <module>
----> 1 for i in MyIter3():
      2     print(i)

<ipython-input-5-82da3324a8a3> in __iter__(self)
     30 
     31     def __iter__(self):
---> 32         for i, j in super().__iter__():
     33             yield i
     34             yield j

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-5-82da3324a8a3> in __iter__(self)
     30 
     31     def __iter__(self):
---> 32         for i, j in super().__iter__():
     33             yield i
     34             yield j

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Can you explain why the second implementation of overriding throws error while the first way works? How can I override `__iter__` with using `super().__iter__()` without getting `RecursionError`?

Can you explain how `__iter__` works in this context of inheritance to understand why `super().__iter__()` refers to the `self`, not the parent?

Comment: I really have tried to answer your question but it is hard to explain. I recommend you to put print statements at the starting of your functions like `print("ExternalIter.__iter__")`, `print("MyIter3.__iter__")` to see what's going on. And to solve your problem, simply return `self.x` in `ExternalIter.__iter__` instead of just `self` and you are good to go. Good question, I wish I had enough English to gave an answer :D

Comment: @Asocia I don't have access to self.x. In the real case, I can only iterate the parent. Parent iterates values as a result of complex  internal calculations.

Comment: Note that `ExternalIter` probably isn't doing what you think it is. Every iterator is simply pulling the next element from a single shared iterator over the list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super().__iter__()` returns `self` *before* the `for` loop makes its own implicit call of `iter(self)`, which kicks off the infinite recursion.

Because of how a `for` loop works, I don't seen any way to use one here. You can use an explicit `while` loop instead to avoid calls to `__iter__`.

```
def __iter__(self):

    while True:
        try:
            i, j = next(self)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        yield i
        yield j
```

This doesn't treat `self` as an iterable, only as an iterator.

Comment: I see the reason. But can you provide a more detailed answer? Is there a way to fix the second overriding issue?